# Swiping the view pager fragment will not move the tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, swipe

I followed these tutorial [Android TabLayout Example using ViewPager and Fragments
Android TabLayout Example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)

But if I swipe the fragment the view pager will not move.
I am getting this result [output I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCdM6.png)
I followed the above tutuorial only no changes, but when we swipe the fragment the tabs will not shift. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

This is the activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- our toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<!-- View pager to swipe views -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show some code. Also there's a default template in Android Studio, when creating an activity, choose Activity with tabs + ViewPager and you'll get a working code that you can examine and learn from it.

Comment: I followed above tutorial working perfectly, except this issue. When i swipe the tabs won't switch why?

Comment: Don't know without your code. Nobody does. Please share relevant code (especially xml where you declared TabLayout).

Comment: make sure you are setting up your viewpager with your tablayout in the Activity : `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(yourViewPager);`

Comment: Did you find problem?

Answer (score 8):

The pages on the viewpager is swiping, that's why it's showing "Tab 3" on page. This is happening due to swiping properties of ViewPager. But the tab is not changing accordingly, that's why is it showing on TAB1. Because there is no link established between tablayout and viewpager.

If you're using a ViewPager together with this tab layout, you can call setupWithViewPager(ViewPager) to link the two together, described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

So no need to call addTab().

```
mTabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

//mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
//mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
//mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
//mTabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

Pager pager = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(),3);
mViewPager.setAdapter(pager);

mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

This tablayout will be automatically populated from the PagerAdapter's page titles. For this in,

```
class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{...

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    super.getPageTitle(position);

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return "Tab1";
        case 1:
            return "Tab2";
        case 2:
            return "Tab3";

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```